# convert Singelton to Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, synchronization

I have created a database object according to the singleton pattern. The database object contains 2 methods: connect() and update().

I want to convert this singelton to Spring bean.

So I've created an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="MySingeltonDB"
        class="SingeltonDBVersion2.SingeltonDB" factory-method="getInstance"></bean>

</beans>
```

adn the SingeltonDB class:

```
package SingeltonDBVersion2;
public class SingeltonDB {
    private static DBconnImpl db = null;
    private static SingeltonDB singalDb = null;

    private SingeltonDB(String username, String password) {
        db = new DBconnImpl();
    }

    public static boolean isOpen() {
        return (db != null);
    }

    public synchronized static SingeltonDB getInstance(String username,
            String password) throws Exception {

        if (db != null) {
            return singalDb;
        }
        System.out.println("The database is now open");
        singalDb = new SingeltonDB(username, password);
        db.connect(username, password);
        System.out.println("The database was connected");
        return singalDb;
    }

    public void create(String tableName) throws Exception {
        db.create(tableName);
    }

    public User query(String tableName, int rowID) throws Exception {
        if (db == null) {
            System.out.println("Error: the database is not open");
            return null;
        }
        return (db.query(tableName, rowID));
    }

    public void update(String tableName, User user) throws Exception {
        if (db == null) {
            System.out.println("Error: the database is not open");
            return;
        }
        db.update(tableName, user);
    }

}
```

and this is the Main class:

```
package SingeltonDBVersion2;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

    }
}
```

but I am getting this error:  ***Error creating bean with name 'MySingeltonDB' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [java.lang.String]: Ambiguous factory method argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as factory method arguments?***

Can somebody please help me? I am new in spring so I might not configured everything proprely...
Thanks!

Comment: Although it mentions a constructor (which is confusing), the message indicates what the problem is: you didn't specify user/password arguments to the factory method.

Comment: An example is available [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-some-examples).

Comment: Thanks!!
Another question. I have this line:
  ApplicationContext db =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
and I want to get the db to act like a SingeltonDB object.. meanining I want to do db.updat()..
I do I solve it?

Comment: You should dig through a bunch of tutorials and figure all of that stuff out, e.g., start from [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/#quick-start). The learning curve can be steep but it is rewarding. I highly recommend reading through a book. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When spring instantiating the singleton it will use 'getInstance' method but this method expecting two parameter: userName and password. But these parameters are not in Spring configuration. You need to add them:

```
<bean id="MySingeltonDB"
        class="SingeltonDBVersion2.SingeltonDB" factory-method="getInstance">
    <constructor-arg value="userName" />
    <constructor-arg value="password" />
</bean>
```

Then you can get MySingletonDB bean from application context:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
SingletonDB singletonDB = (SingletonDB)context.getBean("MySingeltonDB");
singletonDB.update(paramters);
```

Comment: Thanks!!
Another question. I have this line:
  ApplicationContext db =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
and I want to get the db to act like a SingeltonDB object.. meanining I want to do db.updat()..
I do I solve it?

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem. 'db' is not initialized? or simply null? Anyway I would move the db.connect into the constructor -- I see it there logically.

Comment: I have in my hand an object of ApplicationContext (which create a new SingeltonDB). I want to get a reference to this object that was just created (SingeltonDB) so I can do the update on it